# How to access user detail in yii framwork?

Tags: php, drupal, yii

I am beginner in Yii.  I Want to access user_id in whole application. how i can do that?

```
class MainController extends Controller {
    public function actionInitialize() {                   
                             $this->verifyDrupalUserIdentity(); 

          }

 private function verifyDrupalUserIdentity() {
                    new DrupalUserIdentity();                   
          }

}


class DrupalUserIdentity extends CUserIdentity {
 public function __construct() {
                    $this->authenticate();
          }
 public function authenticate(){

                    global $base_url;
                    $base_url = BASE_URL.'CA_Hive';
                    $currentPath = getcwd();
                    require_once DRUPAL_ROOT.'/includes/bootstrap.inc';
                    require_once DRUPAL_ROOT.'/includes/errors.inc';
                    drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
                    chdir($currentPath);

                    global $user;
                    $this->username = $user->name;
                    new DrupalUser();
                    Yii::app()->user->setDrupalAttributes($user);
          }
}
```

**

- Model:-

**

```
    class DrupalUser extends CWebUser {
     private $_attributes;
              private $_browser;
    public $user_id;
     public function setDrupalAttributes($attributes) {
                        $this->_attributes = $attributes;
                        $this->user_id = $this->_attributes->uid;
              }
     public function getUserId() {
return $this->user_id;
}

    }
```

Now i can access user id in **MainController** by using  **Yii::app()->user->getUserId();**

But issue is that, i cannot access user_id in **SecondController** . if i try to access it their, it gives null value. need help.

**SecondController**

```
class SecondController extends Controller {


 public function getUserDetail() {
                   // Here i want the user ID                
          }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need any code in a controller. The current user is represented by the `user` component in Yii. You can access the `id` from everywhere through `Yii::app()->user->id`.

If you want to store custom data for that user, you can extend `CUserIdentity`. Have a look at the manual [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.auth#defining-identity-class) for an example.

Comment: Thats the issue, Yii::app()->user->id. Is giving null value if i use it in secondcontroller.

Comment: Then the user is either not logged in or you somehow override the `getId()` in you custom `WebUser` class. All you should really need is to create your custom UserIdentity where you validate the drupal user and leave the other parts untouched.

Comment: Yes i have override the getId()  as you can see in above code.

Comment: You have a `getUserId()` not a `getId()`. You only should override `getId` in your *user identity* class. It should return the drupal `id` after you successfully identified the user there. Do not override anyhting in the web user.

Comment: it did'nt work for me. may be i was doing something wrong. But i solved my problem by using  Yii::app()->getGlobalState('user_id'); and Yii::app()->setGlobalState('user_id',$uid);

Comment: Do **not** use global state to store a user id!!! Global state is shared across **all** visitors of your site. So if another user logs in, you will overwrite the id of the previous user.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. Sadly i am still unable to get userId in other controller. i have added getId() in CWebUser. this return valid value in MainController. But when i try to access it in SecondController it gives 0 or null; need help

Comment: Also, even Yii::app()->session['uid']; is not working in SecondController, giving me null value.  I want to add that, SecondController is Called via ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

You should show us your `SecondController` code, did you extend it from `Controller` class? By the way, it's one thing, that I can not to ask, what is Drupal here?

Comment: I have edited the above code and has added second controller.  About Drupal , basically my project is getting data from another Drupal project. Data is accurate, i get user detail acuurately and can access it in MainController.

Comment: another drupal project means ?? Where is your actual sign in code ??